# How to get a list of files that already exist on the device with Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to get a list of files from directories, but I never get the name of files that already exist, it just returns the files I created with my app.

For example, inside the Documents folder I have 3 pdf files that I loaded from Android Studio and a test.txt that my app created, but when I run the code to list the files, only test.txt appears.

I already put the permissions in the Manifest, what do I need to do for it to work?

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val externalStorage: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
    private val documentsDir: String = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
    private val documentsPath: String = "$externalStorage/$documentsDir"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        createFile()
        getFilesList(documentsPath)
    }

    private fun createFile() {
        val fileName = "test.txt"
        val file = File(documentsPath, fileName)
        file.writeText("testing file...")
    }

    private fun getFilesList(path: String) {
        File(path).walk()
            .forEach {
                println("WALK: $it")
            }
    }
}
```

The permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" />
```

The logs

```
/com.example.filereaderpoc I/System.out: WALK: /storage/emulated/0/Documents
/com.example.filereaderpoc I/System.out: WALK: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/test.txt
```

My directory tree is like:

```
- DCIM
- Download
- Documents
    test.txt
    test1.pdf
    test2.pdf
    test3.pdf
```

Comment: You only have access to files in `Documents/` that your app created. The same holds true for `Downloads/`.

Comment: `How to get a list of files that already exist ...` Well what about non existing files? Looks just more interesting ;-)

Comment: The two `ACTION_` prefixed values are NOT permissions, they are the names of actions that launch various settings pages. Requesting them as permissions will do nothing useful.